# compiling python file with Watchman

Tags: python, compilation, watchman

what's the best way to capture files/path info from watchman to pass
to 'make' or another app?

here's what im trying to achieve:

when i save a .py(s) file on the dev server, i'd like to retrieve the filename and path, compile the py to pyc, then transfer the pyc file to a staging server.

should i be using watchman-make, 'heredoc' methods, ansible, etc.? 
because the docs are note very helpful, are there any examples available?

and, what's the use case for pywatchman?

thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want a .pyc rather than just using the .py file? I suggest you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893686/where-to-use-a-pyc-file and then decide if you really need the .pyc.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will help clarify some things:

Watchman runs as a per-user service to monitor your filesystem.  It can:

1. Provide live subscriptions to file changes as they occur
2. trigger a command to be run in the background as file changes occur
3. Answer queries about how files have changed since a given point in time

pywatchman is a python client implementation that allows you to build applications that consume information from watchman.  The `watchman-make` and `watchman-wait` tools are implemented using pywatchman.

`watchman-make` is a tool that helps you invoke `make` (or a similar program) when files change.  It is most appropriate in cases where the program you want to run doesn't need the specific list of files that have just changed.  `make` is in this category; `make` will analyze the dependencies in your `Makefile` and then build only the pieces that are changed.  You could alternatively execute a python distutils or setuptools `setup.py` script.

Native watchman triggers are a bit harder to use than `watchman-make`, as they are spawned in the background by the watchman service and are passed the list of changed files.  These are most appropriate for completely unattended processes where you don't need to see the output and need the precise list of changed files.

From what you've described, it sounds like the simplest solution is a script that performs the compilation step and then performs the sync, something along the lines of the following; let's call it `build-and-sync.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m compileall .
rsync -avz . host:/path/
```

(If you don't really need a `.pyc` file and just need to sync, then you can simply remove the `python` line from the above script and just let it run `rsync`)

You can then use `watchman-make` to execute this when things change:

```
watchman-make --make='build-and-sync.sh' -p '**/*.py' -t dummy
```

Then, after any `.py` file (or set of `.py` files) are changed, `watchman-make` will execute `build-and-sync.sh dummy`.  This should be sufficient unless you have a large enough number of python files that the compilation step takes too long each time you make a change.  `watchman-make` will keep running until you hit CTRL-C or otherwise kill the process; it runs in the foreground in your terminal window unless you use something like `nohup`, `tmux` or `screen` to keep it around for longer.

If that is the case, then you can try using `make` with a pattern rule to compile only the changed python files, or if that is awkward to express using make then perhaps it is worth using `pywatchman` to establish a subscription and compile the changed files.  This is a more advanced use-case and I'd suggest looking at the code for [watchman-wait](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/blob/master/python/bin/watchman-wait) to see how that might be achieved.  It may not be worth the additional effort for this unless you have a large number of files or very tight time constraints for syncing.

I'd recommend trying out the simplest solution first and see if that meets your needs before trying one of the more complex options.

## Using native triggers

As an alternative, you can use triggers.  These run in the background with their output going to the watchman log file.  They are a bit harder to work with than using `watchman-make`.

You need to write a small program, typically a script, to receive the list of changed files from the trigger; the best way to do this is via stdin of the script.  You can receive a list of files one-per-line or a JSON object with more structured information.   Let's call this script `trigger-build-and-sync`; it is up to you to implement the contents of the script.  Let's assume you just want a list of files on stdin.

This command will set up the trigger; you invoke it once and it will persist until the watch is removed:

```
watchman -j <<-EOT
["trigger", "/path/to/root", {
   "name": "build-and-sync",
   "expression": ["suffix", "py"],
   "command": "/path/to/trigger-build-and-sync",
   "append_files": false,
   "stdin": "NAME_PER_LINE"
}]
EOT
```

The full docs for this can be found at https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html#extended-syntax

Comment: "...These are most appropriate for completely unattended processes where you don't need to see the output and need the precise list of changed files"

triggers are what i need for unattended processes, but how do i retrieve the list of filenames/paths that watchman provides?  

thanks for your speedy reply

Comment: Watchman will pass you a JSON object containing the list of files on the stdin of your trigger program.  You'll want to use the [extended trigger syntax](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html#extended-syntax) for this and set the `stdin` property to `["name"]` in your trigger definition

Comment: "...I'd recommend trying out the simplest solution first and see if that meets your needs before trying one of the more complex options."  the docs makes it complicated.  all i see are 'heredoc' examples.  so basically, i create a .watchmanconfig file, add the extended json trigger syntax to it, etc.   you mentioned "..on the stdin of your program," suggesting that i create some sort of script/app designed to read stdin as a command placed in my trigger definition?

I also looked at the watchman-wait command.  i got more close to a solution but it doesn't appear to be recursive.  why?  thanks!

Comment: I've expanded the answer above to include more details on triggers.  Watches are definitely recursive.  The example I gave above on using `watchman-make` should do the trick.  Note that `watchman-make` captures the pwd at the time that it is run, so you should cd to your root directory.